# Parallelization of loop in cython

Tags: c++, python, numpy, openmp, cython

With the very help of some members here I did establish a code that runs in Python and evaluates a function that takes two huge `np.arrays` as input.

The vectorized version running in parallel is still massively time consuming and a factor ~50 slower than a reference program written in serial fortran...

I would like to use a cython loop instead for which I can use OpenMP, or MPI to parallelize.
The idea in c++ would be like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i=0;i<np1;i++){
  for (i=0;i<np2;i++){
    double dist = sph(coord1_particle1,coord1_particle2,coord2_particle1,coord2_particle2)
    int bin=binning_function(dist)
    hist_array[bin]++
  }
}
```

Any ideas are totally welcome. Here is the Python version:

```
#a is an array containing two coordinates of two objects
def dist_vec(a): # a like [[array1,array2,array2,array2],[],[]...]
  return sph(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]) # sph operates on coordinates

def vec_chunk(array_ab, bins) :
    dist = dist_vec(array_ab)
    hist, _ = np.histogram(dist, bins=bins)
    return hist


def mp_dist(array_a,array_b, d, bins): #d chunks AND processes
    def worker(array_ab, out_q):
        """ push result in queue """
        outdict = vec_chunk(array_ab, bins)
        out_q.put(outdict)
    # Each process will get 'chunksize' nums and a queue to put his out
    out_q = mp.Queue()
    a = np.swapaxes(array_a, 0 ,1)
    b = np.swapaxes(array_b, 0 ,1)
    array_size_a=len(array_a)-(len(array_a)%d)
    array_size_b=len(array_b)-(len(array_b)%d)
    a_chunk = array_size_a / d
    b_chunk = array_size_b / d
    procs = []
    '''prepare arrays for mp'''
    array_ab = np.empty((4, a_chunk, b_chunk))
    for j in xrange(d):
      for k in xrange(d):
        array_ab[[0, 1]] = a[:, a_chunk * j:a_chunk * (j + 1), None]
        array_ab[[2, 3]] = b[:, None, b_chunk * k:b_chunk * (k + 1)]
        p= mp.Process(target=worker, args=(array_ab, out_q))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)
    for pro in procs:
      pro.join()
    # Collect all results into a single result dict. 
    resultarray = np.empty(len(bins)-1)
    for i in range(d):
        resultarray+=out_q.get() 
        #resultdict.update(out_q.get())
    return resultarray

bins = np.logspace(-3,1, num=25) #prepare x-axis for histogram
start_time = time()
hist_data = mp_dist(DATA,sim,10,bins)
print 'Total Time Elaspsed: ', time() - start_time
```

Answer (score 5):

The following code is ~ 6 times faster than your original one:
It uses faster histogramming code from http://code.google.com/p/astrolibpy/source/browse/my_utils/quick_hist.py (because np.histogram is too slow for bins of uniform length) 
The new code doesn't create that many processes, uses multiprocessing.pool and also avoids extensive copying data between processes.

The rest of the performance can be obtained by rewriting the distance function in cython.
Or even better, rewriting dist_vec() in cython or scipy.weave (see the example in the quick_hist code)

```
import numpy as np,multiprocessing as mp
from time import time
import quick_hist
def sph(a, b, c, d):
    return numexpr.evaluate('log(((a - c)**2 + (b - d)**2)**.5)')

def dist_vec(a,b):
    return sph(a[:,0][:, None], a[:,1][:, None], b[:,0][None, :], b[:,1][None, :]) 

def vec_chunk(a, b, bins) :
    dist = dist_vec(a, b).flatten()
    hist = quick_hist.quick_hist( (dist,), [(bins[0], bins[-1])], [len(bins)])
    return hist

class si:
    # singleton to share read-only data between processes
    a = None
    b = None
    step = None
    bins = None

def func(l1):
    return vec_chunk(si.a[l1:l1+si.step,:], si.b, si.bins)

def mp_dist(array_a,array_b, d, bins): #d chunks 
    nproc = 8  # n processes
    si.a = array_a
    si.b = array_b
    si.step = d
    si.bins = bins
    nx = array_a.shape[0]
    lefts = np.arange(0, nx, d) #left edges of the chunks
    pool = mp.Pool(nproc)   
    results = pool.map(func, lefts)
    results = np.array(results).sum(axis=0)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results

if __name__=='__main__':
    bins = np.logspace(-3,1, num=25) #prepare x-axis for histogram
    start_time = time()
    n1 = 10000
    n2 = 10000
    DATA = np.random.uniform(size=(n1, 2))
    sim = np.random.uniform(size=(n2, 2))
    chunksize = 10
    hist_data = mp_dist(DATA, sim, chunksize, bins)

    print 'Total Time Elaspsed: ', time() - start_time
```

Comment: thanks, your version is even ~12 times faster. I still have to questions. Can I vestorize a function written in cython? I was thinking of writting this function in C-Code.
Can you expain to me what a singleton does roughly?

Comment: I think people usually uses cython to actually go away from vectorization, and to rather directly code the loops. AFAIK this is usually faster in cython (although I don't write much cython code). Regarding the singleton -- that's essentially the structure or class holding the variables, but the key thing here is that it is going to be visible in the child processes created by mp.Pool(). And the memory even doesn't have to be copied.

Comment: That's why I was curious to ask. If I calculate the function `sph` in a loop (let's say for each combination) the vectorization `dist_vec` is useless, right?

Comment: Hi. I think quick_hist is not histogramming dist correctly in log. Can you confirm?

Comment: I'm not aware of any problems with quick_hist, and I'm using it on daily basis. Regarding the vectorizations, if you'll do loops directly in sph(), you won't need broadcasting tricks in dist_vec